# Ошибка при получении изображения с камеры

Tags: java, android, android-camera

Здравствуйте.  Я хочу получить в код изображение в виде Bitmap, после того как что-то сфотографирую.

вот мой код:

```
                 static final int PHOTO_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
                 private Uri outputFileUri;
                 private String img_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/MyApp/imgs/ocr.jpg";


                @Override
                    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);           
                        Button captureImg = (Button) findViewById(R.id.action_btn);
                        captureImg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                startCameraActivity();
                            }
                        });           
                    }

                    private void startCameraActivity() {
                      outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(img_path));

                      Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                      takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
                      if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, PHOTO_REQUEST_CODE);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {

                   super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
                   if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && intent.getData() != null && requestCode == PHOTO_REQUEST_CODE) {                       

                   BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                   options.inSampleSize = 4;
                   Bitmap bitmap =BitmapFactory.decodeFile(outputFileUri.getPath(), options);            

                 // ТУТ Я ХОЧУ РАБОТАТЬ С ЭТОЙ ФОТОГРАФИЕЙ.
               } else {
                   Toast.makeText(this, "ERROR: Image was not obtained.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
    }
```

Но, я получаю следующую ошибку.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.organization.tesseracttest, PID: 29212
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.organization.tesseracttest/com.organization.tesseracttesttest.MainScreen}: java.lang.NullPointerException
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3574)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3617)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:169)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1325)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5476)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                      at com.organization.tesseracttesttest.MainScreen.onActivityResult(MainScreen.java:95)
                      at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5643)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3570)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3617) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:169) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1325) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5476) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099) 
                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8604', transport: 'socket'
```

Я как-бы в принципе не понимаю, почему он ругается. Можете мне объяснить причину почему это происходит, и как поправить ошибку?

Comment: Вы прописали разрешение на использование камеры и памяти в манифесте?

Comment: в манифесте так:

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true" />

Comment: Еще нужно вот это <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"
                  android:required="true" /> Также нужно проверить сами переключатели в настройках приложения.

Comment: Проверьте обновление.

Answer (score 1):

Нашел решение вот здесь https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20536603/null-pointer-after-capturing-image-using-android-camera. Ошибка таже самая, так что должно помочь. Я так понял что дело в том что данные теряются при переходе из камеры обратно в приложение, поэтому вылетает nullpointerexception.

**Обновление**

Если пройти по [ссылке](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html). То можно узнать как сделать все что нужно. Я сделал и у меня работает. Здесь оказывается проблема в том что нужен контент провайдер чтобы передать файл из приложения камера вашему приложению.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Однако это решение мне не помогло. Я продолжаю ловить 

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=null}.

Comment: Вам нужна полноразмерная фотография или миниатюра?